# BackboneJS - Display JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

How do I pass JSON data through a Backbone Model to a view?

my model looks like this:

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "backbone"
],

function($, Backbone) {
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "./bands.php",

    defaults: {
        "id": '',
        "band": '',
        "label": ''
    }
});

return Model;
});
```

my View code looks like:

```
 define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/bandpage.html'],

    function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {


        'use strict';

        var BandpageView = Backbone.View.extend({

            template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

            initialize: function () {
            },

            render: function() {
              this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                  return this;
            }

        });

        return BandpageView;

    }
  );
```

and in my HTML template I have

```
<div>
  <p><%= id %></p>
  <p><%= band %></p>
  <p><%= label %></p>
</div>
```

It doesnt show anything and I get the error **"Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined"**

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your View code.

Comment: ok i pasted my view code

Comment: Where have you created the new instances? new Model and new Bandpageview?

Comment: @SHT: Are you using require.js for organizing your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Update View `initialize` as:

```
initialize: function () {
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
},
```

Create view instance as :

```
var view = new BandpageView({model: new Model()});
```

Comment: this gives me the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Model is not defined

Comment: hmm...still no change. Is it because I have my Models in one folder, my Views in a another folder etc?

Comment: @SHT: Yes. You need to refer Model. Updating my code as per your implementation.

Comment: hmm ok, was actually trying to avoid that. No other solution to that? Can't I refer to the model in my `define([])`- part in my view?

Comment: since i defined my bandpageview in my router, the codeflow you posted doesnt work...man, this is annoying!

Comment: @SHT: Sorry man but question lacks few important things like where instances will be created, router details etc. Would be difficult for someone to assume your coding scenario and help.